# where clause not working in group by LINQ c sharp

Tags: c#, linq, select, group-by, where-clause

I have a table "register_operation with fields"
[Key]
int id_registru_casa ,
DateTime data ,
int id_cont_sintetic ,
decimal suma ,
string tip

tip  can take only 2 value :"receipts" and "payments"

"Groupby" work with no problem
but when I add "where" clause not working
(it doesn't show me any records)
(although there are recordings in database with day 19, month 9 and tip=receipts)

```
        var centralizator_rc = db.register_operation
         .Where(i => (i.data.Day == 19) && (i.data.Month == 9) && (tip=="receipts"))
             .GroupBy(i => i.id_cont_sintetic)
             .Select(g => new {
                 id_cont_sintetic = g.Key,
                 total_receipts = g.Sum(i=>i.suma),
             }).ToList();
```

Thanks!

Comment: Is `tip` related to 'data'? Does changing `(tip=="receipts")` to `(i.data.tip=="receipts")` makes sense?

Comment: Sample data please. In particular is tip always lower case? Your database collation may be case insensitive, which might mislead you.

Comment: @MarkusMeyer I suspect data means date in the OP's language. Tip (type) does not belong to date.

Comment: Yeah, tip might not belong to data, but it currently is also not related to `i` either. So, as currently presented, `tip=="receipts"` appears to be a condition unrelated to the actual individual records from _db.register_operation_. Not sure if that's intentional or not, hence, as Jonathan Willcock already asked for, sample data please.

Comment: "data" and "tip" are the names of the columns in the table "register_operation", they are not data types

Comment: Seems you didn't understand the first comment. How can `&& (tip=="receipts")` even compile? It should be `&& (i.tip=="receipts")`.

Comment: @GertArnold Maybe `tip` is a variable defined somewhere else. `var tip = "receipts";` Then the condition is useless ;-)

Comment: sorry yes it is i.tip in code , it is written wrong here

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED!
I change code like this:

```
var centralizator_rc = db.registru_casa  
            .Where(crc=>(crc.data.Month==8) && (crc.data.Day==16) && (crc.tip=="receipts"))
            .GroupBy(crc=> new
            {
                crc.id_cont_sintetic,
                crc.data.Month,
                crc.data.Day,
                crc.tip
            })                             
            .Select(g => new  {
                data = ziuaOK,
                id_cont_sintetic = g.Key.id_cont_sintetic,
                total_incasare = g.Sum(i => i.suma),
                

            }).ToList();
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).